# Split strings into their alphabetic and numeric components

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013. I want to trim 'words' in Excel that end with numbers, eg:

```
david22
yuvi1
michell555
```

to result in:

```
david   22
yuvi    1
michell 555
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this if you don't want to use vba:

I am assumming your data is in **A column**, so below formula should be kept at **C column**,
Drag this formula untill your data is there in Column A.

```
=+SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&A1,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW($1:$25),1))*ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10)
```

**THEN**

use the below formula in **column B** and drag it to last.

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(C1,A1)-1)
```

Hope this helps

Attached is screenshot for your reference.

[image]

**Some Caveat:**

1) - The input string in **column A** must be shorter than 25 characters

2) - There must be at most 14 digits in the input string. (Any following digits will be shown as zeroes.)

But for the question you asked it should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of examples available in Web ..

Let say u have a data in A column with Header ..

The below work splits text in b column , numbers in c column

```
Sub Seperate()
Dim r As Range, rC As Range
Dim v As Variant

Set r = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "(\d+|\D+)"
    .Global = True
    For Each rC In r
        v = Split(Mid(.Replace(rC.Value, "|$1"), 2), "|")
        rC.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(v) + 1).Value = v
    Next rC
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste Special in to Word as Unformatted Text. With Use wildcards Find what: `([A-z])([0-9])` and Replace All with Replace with: `\1 \2`. Copy results back into Excel and apply Text to Columns with space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The text editor Vi or Vim can do this work.

Line 1: `age231`

Line 2: `open432`

Line 3: `bit042`

The command `1,3s/\(\D\)\(\d\)/\1\t\2/g` in the command mode can do what you want.